# Creating an SQL function to return a bit when it does a check for data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote an SQL query that works great, but am having a hard time converting into a function and could use some advice.

here is the SQL query

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN COUNT(EXPORT_DATE) >=1 AND COUNT(IMPORT_DATE) >=1 AND COUNT(LOCATION)>=1 THEN
CAST (1 AS BIT)
ELSE
CAST (0 AS BIT)
END AS ISTHERE
FROM data_tables
WHERE EXPORT_DATE = '1/1/2020' AND IMPORT_DATE = '1/5/2020' AND LOCATION = 'ENTER LOCATION HERE'
```

This returns a 1 or 0 if all those conditions are met in a column called ISTHERE

I am trying to turn this into a function so I can call it and am getting stuck

```
CREATE FUNCTION duplicate_data (@exportdate date, @importdate date, @location varchar(255))
RETURNS BIT
AS 
BEGIN
SELECT
CASE WHEN COUNT(EXPORT_DATE) >=1 AND COUNT(IMPORT_DATE) >=1 AND COUNT(LOCATION)>=1 THEN
CAST (1 AS BIT)
ELSE
CAST (0 AS BIT)
END AS ISTHERE
FROM data_tables
WHERE EXPORT_DATE = '1/1/2020' AND IMPORT_DATE = '1/5/2020' AND LOCATION = 'ENTER LOCATION HERE'
RETURN ISTHERE
END
```

I get 2 errors

1. Select Statements included within a function cannot return data to a client
2. invalid column name = ISTHERE

Still new to writing functions, where is my syntax incorrect?

This is for Microsoft SQL Server and all 3 conditions must be met.

many thanks

DamnGroundHog

Comment: Is the goal of the function to determine when you have more than one record in the same table that meet the three criteria in your where clause?

Comment: Don't use localized date literals. Use `YYYYMMDD` or `YYYY-MM-DD` if the type is `date`. Anything else is parsed using the current locale, which can lead to errors or worse, unexpected results. What is `4/7/2020`? July 4 or April 7? There's no way to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both errors are telling you the problem here:

> Select Statements included within a function cannot return data to a client

You have a scalar function, so, as the error tells you, you can't have a `SELECT` that returns data to the client.

> Invalid column name = ISTHERE

in the statement `RETURN ISTHERE` the column `ISTHERE` has no context, so hence the error.

Scalar functions work with variables for returning, so what you actually want is:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.duplicate_data (@exportdate date, @importdate date, @location varchar(255))
RETURNS BIT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IsThere bit;
    SET @IsThere = (SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(EXPORT_DATE) >=1 AND COUNT(IMPORT_DATE) >=1 AND COUNT(LOCATION)>=1 THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)  
                                                                                                              ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
                           END
                    FROM dbo.data_tables
                    WHERE EXPORT_DATE = @exportdate
                      AND IMPORT_DATE = @importdate
                      AND LOCATION = @location)
    RETURN @IsThere;
END;
```

Comment: Worked exactly as you wrote it.  Thanks for explaining scaler functions, this is my first one.  with your explanation, it all makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Because of your `where` conditions, you can drastically simplify the query to:

```
select (case when count(*) >= 1 then 1 else 0 end)
from dbo.data_tables
where EXPORT_DATE = @exportdate and
      IMPORT_DATE = @importdate and
      LOCATION = @location;
```

Then you can write this as a scalar inline function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION duplicate_data (
    @exportdate date,
    @importdate date,
    @location varchar(255)
)RETURNS BIT
AS 
    RETURN (select convert(bit, (case when count(*) >= 1 then 1 else 0 end))
            from dbo.data_tables
            where EXPORT_DATE = @exportdate and
                  IMPORT_DATE = @importdate and
                  LOCATION = @location
           );
```